# Why check if typeof X is 'undefined' insted of checking if X is undefined?

Tags: typescript

I've read [this article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2022/03/28/optional-undefined-typescript/), where it is suggested to check against possible `undefined` properties with this code:

```ts
function addOne(foo: Foo): number {
    if (typeof foo.bar !== 'undefined') {
        return foo.bar + 1;
    }
    throw new Error('bar is undefined');
}
```

I'm surprised because I'd say `typeof foo.bar !== 'undefined'` is equivalent to `foo.bar !== undefined` but more verbose.

Is there any advantage of the first over the second?

Comment: The only difference I can think of is in the edge case where the name `undefined` is reassigned a different value. To be clear, you should never do that! But JavaScript doesn't stop you from doing it.

Comment: @kaya3 even then, if you really want to guard against that wouldn't `foo.bar !== void 0` be shorter?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir It would be shorter, but it is not in one of the specific forms of condition which Typescript recognises as a type guard. (That said, of course I would always write `!== undefined` myself, I'm just addressing why this other person might have written it that way/what the difference is.)

Comment: Actually, on inspection, `!== void 0` *is* recognised as a type guard. TIL! [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvARgQwE4H4BcUAdgK4C26E2AvgLABQDAZiUQMbACWcRUmAJvwDyRCAAomCQvDgBKQqQpU0DKGqicmUCQgB0WbFACESFADc4nflAAMslfXVOo2CMBLZekuPpxQA1FAAjADcqup0jurAABbYcADuxBBJAKLY8dhiAOQGGgDOUKz8EEycovzZsmH0kUA)